# Disable chunked transfer encoding in AWS SDK for S3 in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way using the AWS SDK in C# to disable chunked transfer encoding for object writes and reads?  I can't seem to find a way to do this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youc can use UseChunkEncoding flag in  PutObjectRequest

like

```
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
request.UseChunkEncoding = false;
```